# Generate a property as schema definition in OpenApi 3.0

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

When using swagger 2.0, the `java.util.Currency` class got generated as a seperate definition. But when we generate OpenAPI 3.0, we run into the issue that swagger-core generates it as a property.

---

#### Generation of the OpenAPI 3.0 specification from the classes

We have f.e. this class:

```
import java.util.Currency; 

public class Wrapper {
   private Currency currency;
}
```

From this code we generate the openapi specification with the following plugin configuration:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputFileName>openapi</outputFileName>
                <outputFormat>YAML</outputFormat>
                <outputPath>....</outputPath>
                <resourcePackages>...</resourcePackages>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resolve</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When generated this will result in this component definition:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Wrapper:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        currency:
          type: object
          properties:
            currencyCode:
              type: string
            defaultFractionDigits:
              type: integer
              format: int32
            numericCode:
              type: integer
              format: int32
            displayName:
              type: string
            symbol:
              type: string
```

---

#### Generation of the classes from the OpenAPI 3.0 specification

We then then generate the classes in another project with the following plugin:

The code to generate the classes form this openapi specification:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>openapi-generation</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>java</language>
                        <library>jersey2</library>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>
                            <booleanGetterPrefix>is</booleanGetterPrefix>
                            <dateLibrary>threetenbp</dateLibrary>
                            <import-mappings>
                                Currency=java.util.Currency
                            </import-mappings>
                        </configOptions>
                        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                        <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                        <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This will result in a class named `WrapperCurrency`. The `--import-mappings` option does not seem to work since it's a property and not a `schema`. This would work if the Currency would be generated as a seperate Schema definition.

---

#### Desired result

Is there any way to either, annotate the property in such a way that the `java.util.Currency` will be generated as a schema? something along the lines of:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Wrapper:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        currency:
           $ref: "components/schemas/Currency"

    Currency:
      type: object
      properties:
        currencyCode:
          type: string
        defaultFractionDigits:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        numericCode:
            type: integer
            format: int32
        displayName:
          type: string
        symbol:
          type: string
```

Or is there a way to bind the `--import-mappings` option to a property instead of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you may consider a workaround: adding an annotation `@Schema(ref = "Currency")` to the currency field will make the plugin skip generating properties. Unfortunately, it won't generate the schema definition for the Currency class either:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Wrapper:
      type: object
      properties:
        currency:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Currency'
```

I am not sure if it is an issue for you, as you are mapping it back to `java.util.Currency` anyways. But if it is, there is another hack: you can provide a static file with a partial schema (just the Currency definition) and configure the plugin to merge it with the generated schema (`openapiFilePath` parameter).

Plugin configuration:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <configuration>
                ...
                <openapiFilePath>src/main/resources/currency.yaml</openapiFilePath>
                ...
            </configuration>
            ...
      </plugin>
```

currency.yaml:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Currency:
      type: object
      properties:
        currencyCode:
          type: string
        defaultFractionDigits:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        numericCode:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        displayName:
          type: string
        symbol:
          type: string
```

It's a hack, I know, but if there are no other options...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it's not a perfect solution, it is one. We'll investigate further if this is the way we want to go. For now I'll award the bounty to you and if we do decide to follow this route, I'll mark this answer as accepted